# JSON Being Re-Sorted - AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JSON that I have sorted with PHP which is then used by JQuery for other tasks. When I sort the JSON on the server, the order outputs correctly. When I am back on the client and I use the following, it returns my JSON back to its original order.

```
        success: function(json){
            console.log(json);
            var js = Object.values(JSON.parse(json));
            console.log(js);
```

**LOG 1 STRING**

> {
>       "304": {
>           "key": "K01",
>           "default_title": "SAMPLE",
>           "big_stamp": "010208231674",
>           "date_stamp": "0102",
>           "time_stamp": "08231674",
>           "real_title": "ABC123",
>           "display_title": "ABC123",
>           "display_stamp": "Jan 2nd - 8:23:16 am"
>       }, ...

**LOG 2 ARRAY**

> 0: key: "A01" default_title: "SAMPLE" big_stamp: "092000000000"
>   date_stamp: "0920" time_stamp: "00000000" real_title: "Test Title"
>   display_title: "Test Title (3)" display_stamp: "Sep 20th - 12:00:00
>   am"
>   **proto**: Object

The original order is by `key` and the new order should be by `display_title`.

Comment: what is `json`? is it a string, is it an object?

Comment: https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#_traversal-order-of-properties

Comment: Order is typically not honored in Objects. If you really want order, use an array. So my guess is the parsing builds the object and reorders the keys.

Answer (score 1):

While this question was badly received I would still like to share my solution. Because the order was not kept above I decided to create a new JSON array before returning to the client. I did this with the following in PHP:

```
$i=0;
$new = array();
foreach($json as $record){
    $new[$i] = $record;
    $i++;
}
```